# Convolution of Gaussian with exponential decay?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors

I need to convolve an exponential decay (defined as the exponential $Ae^{-\lambda t}$ from $0$ to $+\infty$) with a Gaussian of known standard deviation $\sigma$, in other words I need to compute the following integral:

$$ g(\tau) = \int_{0}^\infty \exp(-\lambda t) \exp\left(-\frac{(t-\tau)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)\mathrm d t $$

which is almost the same integral as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685041/convolute-exponential-with-a-gaussian) question, but with a $0$ as the lower limit.

The answer to the Math exchange question above does not seem to apply here, or at least not for the whole range of the convolution: naively I would expect an exponential increase up to $\tau=0$, then a Gaussian-like peak and finally an exponential decay for large $\tau$.

Anyway know how to get the full mathematical expression? **SOLVED**

**REAL QUESTION**: And by the way -  am I doing this right? I have a lot of data for particle momenta, creation and end vertices: from these I'm calculating the rest lifetime for each particle event and plotting it in a histogram. The tail does look like an exponential decay but close to $t =0$ there's a Gaussian-like behaviour. If we assume that the detector resolution will smear the data with a Gaussian, the final plot of lifetimes should look like the convolution of an exponential decay with a Gaussian, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Laplace transform of a Gaussian function, which is well known, e.g. [done here](http://planetmath.org/laplacetransformofagaussianfunction), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). You will have to expand the square to make use of the identities, of course.

Comment: Thanks, so that's solved. What about the physical interpretation question?

Comment: I don't really have a good feel for what you are measuring, but probably because I haven't had time to give it enough thought. Are you sure you don't need a Poissonnian distribution?